# how to save data as null in database in Django forms

Tags: python, django

here is my problem "Do something in the input form so that the subject value does not need to be filled when sending and it is saved in the database without any input."  it is an important task for me I'll be so grateful if you help me

models.py

```py
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Contact(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField()
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    message = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created_date']
    
    def __srt__(self):
        return self.name
```

```
forms.py


from django import forms
from website.models import Contact

class ContactForm(forms.ModelForm):
    subject = forms.CharField(required=False)
    
    class Meta:
        model = Contact 
        fields = "__all__"
```

views.py

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from website.forms import ContactForm
from django.contrib import messages

def index_view(request):
    return render(request, "website/index.html")

def about_view(request):
    return render(request, "website/about.html")

def contact_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        request.POST._mutable = True
        request.POST['name'] = 'Anonymous'
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, "your ticket submited")
        else:
            messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, "your ticket did not submited")
    form = ContactForm()
    return render(request, "website/contact.html", {"form:form})
```

i try somethings in model but it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to do so you have to  make the field that you need to be optional nullable, for example if you want to make the email optional you would edit the field in the model like this:

```
email = models.EmailField(blank=True, null=True)
```

and also in the form needs to be not required like this:

```
email = forms.EmailField(required=False)
```

so based on your requirements you need to edit the declaration of subject in your model to like this:

```
subject = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True)
```

Comment: thanks  i tried this but it doesn't work

Comment: can you provide your templates and screenshots of the error

Comment: i forget about makemigrations :)

Comment: can you answer my new question?